# How to make a user see dashboards based upon hierarchy?

Tags: dashboard

I have tried to change the settings as logged in user but the user is still able to see all the data. Also I want to change the settings for all the four dashboards but it is allowing me to change it to run as logged in user. The error message says that Run as logged-in user
Error: You reached the limit for dashboards run as the logged-in user.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Developer Edition, the dynamic dashboards per org = up to 3

For Unlimited & Performance Edition, the dynamic dashboards per org = up to 10

For Enterprise Edition, the dynamic dashboards per org = up to 5

I believe the number of dynamics dashboards can be increased for an additional cost. You will need to get in touch with your account manager.

Reference: http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/16/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf

Referred this info from: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DcilQAC

Also, this issue is there in Idea community of SFDC: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IRSu